# PHP charset and "\n"

Tags: php, post, character-encoding

So, my problem is that I'm trying to send a mail via PHP. And I want all of these posts to be on one row each. However with the $header = "content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; this seems impossible. And of course if I remove that piece of code I can't show åäö in my mails. I've been at this for 2 days now.

```
<?php

$to = "info@mywebsite.se";
$subject = "Bokning från hemsidan.";
$header = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: bokning@mywebsite.se\r\n";
$body = "En bokning:" . "\n\n" .
    $_POST["namn"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["mobilnummer"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["hemnummer"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["email"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["gatuadress"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["postnummer"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["vaning"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["portkod"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["bokningsdag"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["byggstadning"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["flytthjalp"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["flyttstadning"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["typavbostad"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["fonsterputsning"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["kontorsstadning"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["rojningbortforsling"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["visningsstad"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["dodsbo"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["boyta"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["kallare"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["vind"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["totalkvm"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["garage"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["forrad"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["veranda"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["balkongglas"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["balkongejglas"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["friggebod"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["fakgatuadress"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["fakpostnummer"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["jarut"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["nejrut"] . "\n" .
    $_POST["meddelande"];


if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = "Tack för din bokning! Vi kommer att kontakta dig inom kort via mail eller telefon för att bekräfta din bokning. Vid bråskande ärenden var vänlig ring kontoret. Våra telefontider är 8.00-12.30.";
}
?>
```

Comment: What about this seems impossible? Exactly what failure do you see when you try it?  Post the code that fails.  Post the error message.  Post a description of the failure.  Post steps to reproduce.

Comment: what seems impossible is to combine the two things. meaning, both be able to see åäö and such and have the mail written on seperate lines insted of just one like it becomes now

Comment: You still need to answer the rest of my comment.  Repeating yourself doesn't clarify things.  Adding additional detaions taht are asked for adds clarification

Comment: Ok, my misstake, let me try again. The piece of code i have produces a mail and in that mail i want all of the information to be on seperate lines, this is why i've used the "\n". However without the $header = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; i cannot see åäö in the mail. BUT with it it does. Although it puts all the information in the mail on a single row, making it very difficult to read.

And the code that ive posted is the code that is failing. It doesnt give me any errors but the mail that it sends doesnt turn out like i want it to. However it DOES send it.

Comment: OK. So it sounds like you're looking to figure out how to insert a line break in a UTF-8 email, but you're getting the value "åäö" within the email message itself when you do this.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

\r\n works for e-mail newlines, as required by [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822):

> Messages are divided into lines of characters.  A line is a series of
> characters that is delimited with the two characters carriage-return
> and line-feed; that is, the carriage return (CR) character (ASCII
> value 13) followed immediately by the line feed (LF) character (ASCII
> value 10).  (The carriage-return/line-feed pair is usually written in
> this document as "CRLF".)

See also: [Comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#68271) regarding "low quality Unix MTAs" requiring \n instead of \r\n

`\r` is CR, `\n` is LF in PHP

I probably should have stated that this is only valid for `Content-Type:text/plain`, but mail systems are supposed to be created to fit all relevant RFCs from the Internet Engineering Task Force including the above-mentioned section. If you are sending HTML instead, use `<BR />` instead.

Comment: `\r\n` is only required for header sections and MIME content dividers. The message bodies can have whatever they want for line breaks.

Comment: GMail host doesn't work with `\r\n` as far as I know. It should be a single `\n`.

Comment: From the comments on [Mail on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with RFC 2822.

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net, you must separate each line with "\r\n".

Comment: `\r\n` is only required for header sections and MIME content dividers. The message bodies can have whatever they want for line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, \r\n is the line break for the email headers.  If you look at the Wikipedia page on "Newline", you'll see several representations of the character.

> Systems based on ASCII or a compatible character set use either LF
>   (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal) or CR (Carriage return, '\r',
>   0x0D, 13 in decimal) individually, or CR followed by LF (CR+LF,
>   '\r\n', 0x0D0A)
>
> The Unicode standard defines a large number of characters that
>   conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:[4]
>   LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
>   ...
>   CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D

You might try passing "\0\r\0\n" within your UTF-8 body and see if you get the line breaks you're hoping for.